# Configuring Hadoop to Process Input File as one Map Task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am doing a MapReduce with a Single 200MB file. My target is to finish in 1 map task. I did:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.min.split.size","999999999999999");
```

But still, it seems that the number of records is restricting me. Is it the cause of the splitting map task? If so, what can I do to change it?

```
14/03/20 00:12:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
14/03/20 00:12:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
14/03/20 00:12:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapred.min.split.size` generally form the lower limit for creating input splits, while the DFS block size is 128MB. So in your case, the lower limit is more than the higher limit, and it seems that hadoop doesn't care for that and goes with the higher limit and split the input data accordingly.

Quoting from wiki:

> Actually controlling the number of maps is subtle. The
>   mapred.map.tasks parameter is just a hint to the InputFormat for the
>   number of maps. The default InputFormat behavior is to split the total
>   number of bytes into the right number of fragments. However, in the
>   default case the DFS block size of the input files is treated as an
>   upper bound for input splits. A lower bound on the split size can be
>   set via mapred.min.split.size. Thus, if you expect 10TB of input data
>   and have 128MB DFS blocks, you'll end up with 82k maps, unless your
>   mapred.map.tasks is even larger. Ultimately the InputFormat determines
>   the number of maps.

The hint for you is in the last sentence, so if you want to control the numer of mappers, you have to override `InputFormat`, generally we use `FileInputFormat` and it's `isSplittable()` method needs to be overridden to return `false`. That would ensure that there is one mapper per file.
Something like follows will siffice:

```
Class NonSplittableFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat{

    @Override
    public boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename){ 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before, doesn't work. TextInputFormat splits my file into one record per row. It seems when it has >262144 records, it will automatically spill to a new mapper.

Comment: Oh is it! That's strange. So are you saying that even with isSplittable() returning false, the file is split? I do not think hadoop is at all concerned by number of records in a file, it splits according to it's file size and the DFS block size.

Comment: Haha.. That's what I read too, though I am not really familiar with the concept of spill